# How come Eclipse IDE executing AutoIt script breaks page layout, but not when debugging?

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium-chromedriver, autoit

Having a very strange problem, been trying to debug it with no success. I'm automating a web application using Selenium Webdriver in Java using Eclipse as the IDE. In the process of diagnosing, Chrome, Eclipse and the Java project (via Maven) have all been updated.

One area of test case coverage involves opening an upload file picker within Chrome, selecting a file, and clicking Open to upload the file and close the picker. As Selenium cannot interact with these pickers I invoke `Runtime.getRuntime().exec()` to run a simple AutoIt script, along with the filepath:

```
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")
```

Historically, this script has worked perfectly and has no obvious reason to break.

At the point where the Runtime line above is ran in the project, the rendering of the page will change. The entire page appears ~30 pixels higher than normal. If you mouse-over any button they will not be clickable unless you move your mouse 30px down to the empty space below. This breaks any further automation because buttons are no longer clickable.

In reproducing this I made the following discoveries:

1. This cannot be reproduced manually.
2. While debugging, I set a breakpoint at the runtime line (which appears to be the line causing the issue). If I click Resume the problem appears at the point it executes the Runtime line. If I click Step Over/Step Into, it executes the Runtime line *without* causing the problem.
3. Refreshing the page manually fixes the rendering issue.
4. Refreshing the page via Selenium does not fix the rendering issue, and so is not a workaround.

I am totally lost. Manual input is the only way to temporarily resolve the issue, which defeats the point of automation. I have not seen anyone else have the same problem.

Comment: Thats odd. The window title is probably 30px. Try playing with Opt("MouseCoordMode", 1) ;1=absolute, 0=relative, 2=client
And see if it has any effect

Comment: I guess you run the Autoit script AFTER you have clicked the page in order to show the upload form? Does the script work as expected, apart from braking the page? That 30px offset, how did you find out about it? selenium fails clicking the elements?

Comment: Try setting the WinWait and run autoit before you run the selenium and see what happens. I'm pretty sure Autoit isn't the problem here.

Comment: Yes, selenium clicks the upload button to bring up the file picker. Then the runtime line executes, triggering the autoit script to select the file picker, type in a path, and click 'open'. The autoit part works perfectly every time.
AutoIT doesn't seem to have any issues clicking the objects on the picker at all. But at the point it is executed, the actual webpage itself (underneath the file picker) goes wonky and then selenium has problems clicking anything afterwards. As selenium is running through a series of steps, including opening the picker, I'm not sure how autoIT could be run first.

Comment: As for the 30px offset, it's just an estimation. But I can see the page shift visually as I watch the automation execute. If I interrupt execution it with a breakpoint and start clicking around, I find the buttons are not interactive with my mouse unless I move it below the buttons about 30px. Once this happens, and the autoIT script ends, selenium fails to click the elements and throws an exception, failing the test which is how I found the problem originally as all tests relying on this series of actions started failing.

Comment: I'll try using the MouseCoordMode switch, but since that's part of autoIT which is not having any problems on its own, it may be fruitless.

Comment: Yeah, MouseCoordMode will be useless...

Comment: Run this before running the browser and see if its any different.

WinWait("Open")
ControlFocus("Open","","Edit1")
ControlSetText("Open","","Edit1", $CmdLine[1])
ControlClick("Open","","Button1")

Comment: Its a very odd bug. Try pausing one second before you execute Autoit code and see if it works

Comment: @Milos I've tried pausing 2 seconds, and using the WinWait("Open") separately, and neither of them have resolved it. :(
I'll play around with the driver options in selenium some more to see if it's something like that

Comment: can you try the autoit script with only one line at a time to see which line might be causing the shift? maybe try `ControlSend()` instead of `ControlSetText()`? maybe try focusing the web application window/control inside the autoit script at various times to see if this has any effect?